# How many 4digit numbers with hexadecimal characters can be generated without repetition?

Tags: combinations, permutation, computer-science

for example we can have 1234, 1342, 1413,.... But not  like 1223. And also 2 4digit numbers should not have all the exact same elements (for example : like 1234 and 3214)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking a programming-related question.

Comment: There are only 65,536 combinations.  Write a program to test them all! :)

Comment: This is really a discrete math problem and not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is a programming problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int hasdups ( char * x ) {
        return ((x[0] == x[1]) || (x[0] == x[2]) || (x[0] == x[3]) ||
                (x[1] == x[2]) || (x[1] == x[3]) || (x[2] == x[3]));
}

int main  ( void ) {

        int     bad[65536] = { 0 };
        char    hex[5];
        int     i;
        int     n       = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 65536; ++i) {
                if (bad[i]) continue;
                sprintf(hex, "%04x", i);
                if (hasdups(hex)) {
                        bad[i] = 1;
                } else {
                        /* we could write code to enumerate the 24 permutations
                           of this number: abcd abdc acbd acdb ... dcba
                           and mark the other 23 off in bad OR we can just... */
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 65536; ++i) n += (bad[i] == 0);

        printf("%d combinations meet the criteria\n", n/24);    /* ... divide */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you can just compute `(16*15*14*13)/24` :)

Comment: could you also write a code to generate them in order please?

Comment: I could.  But you should be able to figure that out from the code already there.